# Google Maps InfoWindow withAurelia

Tags: google-maps, aurelia

I have a problem where I want to show certain information depending on if the information is null or not.

```
infowindow.setContent(`<b show.bind="${info != null}> Info : ${info}</b>`);
```

I can't seem to get it to work. Is this possible at all ?

Comment: Can't see the full code, but I can see that you are missing a closing double quote after the *show.bind=* expression.

Comment: Yeah sorry was not copy pasted code. Was written  y hand. The code is correctly written just not sure it's possible to use aurelia in infowindows created by Google

Comment: I don't think the question is specific to google. Try to simply inject content the same way into an element in the page. Such as *$("body").append(`<b show.bind="${info != null}> Info : ${info}</b>`)*.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You'd have to use aurelia-templating-engine to enhance `infowindow` contents after calling `setContent`. However, it would be 
 a lot easier if you just reset infowindow's content whenever `info` changes. I can provide an example if you want

Comment: @FabioLuz Would love an example.

Comment: @MattiasGreger done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that `info` is a property of your class:

```typescript
import { observable } from 'aurelia-framework'; 

export class MyClass {

  // if the property is not bindable you should use @observable, otherwise you just keep @bindable
  @observable() 
  private info: string;

  private infoChanged() {
    const content = info ? `<b> Info : ${info}</b>` : ''; 
    infowindow.setContent(content);
  }
}
```

This is easier than enhancing and will solve the problem.